# How to fix this error while installing a module with expo

Tags: react-native, cmd, expo

I'm trying to install a module (DateTimePicker for Expo).

Accordingly to documentation we have to use the following command:

```
expo install @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

**However, when executing that command,  [this error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ftq.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to expo, is because you are using the new npm dependencies.
So you only need to follow the error message

expo install @react-native-community/datetimepicker --legacy-peer-deps